# How do you find out which version of GTK+ is installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I need to determine which version of GTK+ is installed on Ubuntu

Man does not seem to help

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126145/) will tell you which minor version of 2.0 is installed. Different major versions will have different package names because they can co-exist on the system (in order to support applications built with older versions).

Even for development files, which normally would only let you have one version on the system, you can have a version of gtk 1.x and a version of gtk 2.0 on the same system (the include files are in directories called gtk-1.2 or gtk-2.0).

So in short there isn't a simple answer to "what version of GTK is on the system". But...

Try something like:

```
dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'
```

to list all the libgtk packages, including -dev ones, that are on your system. `dpkg -l` will list all the packages that dpkg knows about, including ones that aren't currently installed, so I've used grep to list only ones that are installed (line starts with i).

Alternatively, and probably better if it's the version of the headers etc that you're interested in, use pkg-config:

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+
```

will tell you what version of GTK 1.x development files are installed, and

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0
```

will tell you what version of GTK 2.0. The old 1.x version also has its own gtk-config program that does the same thing. Similarly, for GTK+ 3:

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
```

Comment: Any suggestion for windows ? how to find installed gtk version on windows ?

Comment: The pkg-config program is part of the windows installation. So writing pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0 in the command line should work.

Comment: Pretty sure the `libgtk*` in `dpkg -l libgtk*` has to be enclosed in single quotes (`dpkg -l 'libgtk*'`) to prevent wildcard expansion at the shell level.

Comment: If there are no glob matches, and there probably aren't here, then it wil be passed to the command unexpanded, so this will work. But it would indeed be safer to quote it.

Comment: To check gtkmm try: `pkg-config --modversion gtkmm-3.0`

Comment: pkg-config --modversion gtk4

Answer (score 72):

This isn't so difficult.

Just check your gtk+ toolkit utilities version from terminal:

```
gtk-launch --version
```

Comment: This should be the solution to the question

Comment: I agree, why is this not the top vote as a simple solution with the rest of the answers available for more in-depth analysis?

Comment: it shows version 3 when I have also version 4 instaled

Comment: Works on Archlinux

Comment: doesnt work on mobian, (debian version for smartphones) used pkgconfig instead.

Comment: Best one liner (accepted answer is overkill).

Comment: This shows the wrong version for me...

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, which, to my knowledge, ships with GTK 4, but this command says GTK 3 instead.

Answer (score 28):

**get GTK3 version:**

```
dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version'
```

or just version number

```
dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version' | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use this command:

```
$ dpkg -s libgtk2.0-0|grep '^Version'
```

Comment: This was getting minor versions of GTK+ 2, but GTK+ 3 has been out for years now and GTK+ 4 in on the way.

Answer (score 9):

You could also just compile the following program and run it on your machine.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize GTK */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    g_printf("%d.%d.%d\n", gtk_major_version, gtk_minor_version, gtk_micro_version);
    return(0);
}
```

compile with ( assuming above source file is named version.c):

```
gcc version.c -o version `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

When you run this you will get some output. On my old embedded device I get the following:

```
[root@n00E04B3730DF n2]# ./version 
2.10.4
[root@n00E04B3730DF n2]#
```

Comment: If I compile as you say, I get 2.24.27. If I compile with `--libs gtk+-3.0` instead, I get 3.10.8. This just seems to tell me that I have development files for both, but not which I'm using at the moment.

Comment: gtkv.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @tsbertalan "using at the moment" depends upon what version of GTK your various apps are linked against.

Comment: it does not compile on gtk4. gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) w.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)
w.c: In function ‘main’: w.c:10:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘gtk_init’

Answer (score 7):

Try,

```
apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

or,

```
dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a distribution-independent way is:

`gtk-config --version`

Comment: While gtk-config is distribution independent, it only works for GTK 1.x. The correct way for newer versions is to use pkg-config, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just open synaptic and search for libgtk, it will show you exactly which lib is installed.

Answer (score 3):

Because `apt-cache policy` will list all the matches available, even if not installed, I would suggest using this command for a more manageable shortlist of GTK-related packages installed on your system:

```sh
apt list --installed libgtk*
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 dpkg-query -W libgtk-3-bin
```

Comment: This was the only answer that behaved differently when I substituted `2` for `3`.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the version of the GTK libraries for GTK 2, 3, and 4.

```
dpkg -l | egrep "libgtk(2.0-0|-3-0|-4)"
```

As major versions are parallel installable, you may have several of them on your system, which is my case, so the above command returns this on my Ubuntu Trusty system:

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64                                      3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6                                   amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64                                     2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4                                  amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

This means I have GTK+ 2.24.23 and 3.10.8 installed.

If what you want is the version of the development files, use:

- `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0` for GTK 2
- `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` for GTK 3
- `pkg-config --modversion gtk4` for GTK 4

(This changed because the `+` from `GTK+` was dropped a while ago.)

Comment: dpkg -l | egrep "libgtk(2.0-0|-3-0|-4)"

Comment: pkg-config --list-all | sed -ne 's/\(gtk[0-9]*.0\).*/\1/p' | xargs pkg-config --modversion gtk4

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the refresher. Don't hesitate to propose an edit to the original post next time ;-).

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer more general than Ubuntu (I have Redhat):

gtk is usually installed under /usr, but possibly in other locations. This should be visible in environment variables. Check with

```
env | grep gtk
```

Then try to find where your gtk files are stored. For example, use `locate` and grep.

```
locate gtk | grep /usr/lib
```

In this way, I found `/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0`, which contains the subdirectory `2.10.0`, which contains many .so library files. My conclusion is that I have gtk+ version 2.10. This is rather consistent with the rpm command on Redhat: `rpm -qa | grep gtk2`, so I think my conclusion is right.

Comment: second method works

Answer (score 1):

To compile and link a GTK program with `pkg-config`, we need the library name instead of the actual version number. For example, the following command compiles and links a GTK program that uses the GTK4 library:

```
gcc -o program program.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
```

To obtain the library name for GTK, use the following command:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use `rpm -q gtk4` and then replace the 4 with a 3 if you want the GTK3 version.