# Hard to see state of check boxes in Eclipse dark theme

Tags: eclipse

I'm fairly new to using the Eclipse IDE, and have downloaded and am running Oxygen Release (4.7.1a) running on GNOME 2.28.2.  With the "Light" theme, check boxes are easy to distinguish.  However, upon switching to the "Dark" theme, the checks become very faint, and difficult to see unless I look carefully (see screenshot).

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of Preferences, showing checkboxes]

Comment: If it is related to [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519576) then it should be fixed in [this developer build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/I20171023-0800/#EclipseSDK). Otherwise you have to report it to Eclipse. Which GTK version do you have?

Comment: I'm running on GTK 3.14.15 (assuming I followed [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126141/how-do-you-find-out-which-version-of-gtk-is-installed-on-ubuntu) properly).

Comment: Could you try the developer build to check if it has already been fixed?

Comment: Sorry- yes, I tried it, and no, it was not fixed.

Comment: Too bad. Please report it to Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=SWT&version=4.7.1a&op_sys=Linux&comment=See+also+https://stackoverflow.com/q/46894432/6505250