# Detect availability of GTK3 in shell script

Tags: bash, gtk3

We want to avoid the user to make changes to our application start script of only GTK2 is available, but not GTK3. What is the preferred way to detect the availability of GTK3?

Comment: Which OS are you targeting?

Comment: Maybe this will help you ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126141/how-do-you-find-out-which-version-of-gtk-is-installed-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Linux** and regardless of if it's based on **rpm** or **deb,** a generic form of getting **gtk** library versions could be

```
find /usr/lib64/ -name 'libgtk*' | xargs readelf -d |\
gawk 'BEGIN{ FS="[[]|[]]"}{if($0 ~ /SONAME/){ print $2 }}' | sort | uniq
```

Result:

```
libgtk-3.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

With that, it's possible to get available GTK versions.