# When I open the dialog box in Eclipse the backgroung goes white

Tags: eclipse

When i open any dailog box in eclipse the backgroung goes dark white and blurry so it difficult to work on it i give the screen shot of that
[image]

it is difficult to find the word in this type of condition so what i do for to see my code

Comment: This looks like an outdated version of Eclipse. Does an upgrade fix the problem? If not, which GTK version are you using?

Comment: how i know that what GTK verision i have

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/126141/6505250

Comment: @MrRobot Could you fix it?