# Eclipse IDE fades when not focused (impossible to read)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ide, window

I just changed my OS (Ubuntu) to an SSD and this never happen before.

When I'm using the Eclipse ide, every time it loses focus it fades (when I click away for example), adding like a transparent layer over.

[image: Screenshot of a faded Eclipse window]
About my Eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53045492/6505250). The blurring of the background is done by Linux, not by Eclipse. Since Eclipse Photon (4.8) [`GTK_THEME` is supported](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#gtk3-theme-override-support) which might be used to fix the issue without changing the theming for other applications. Is there a reason why you are using such an old Eclipse version?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll check if I am allowed to update it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update Eclipse to the latest version