# Eclipse crashes with Problematic frame: C [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x3b660] g_str_hash+0x0

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638

which keeps on crashing for some reason. This crashing usually happens when I try to navigate between classes using references ( Ctrl + Mouse click ). Also when I try to syncronize with SVN repository it crashes. These are few instances which creates error log file having following content.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb6ae09b660, pid=29515, tid=29587
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.2+7) (build 15.0.2+7-27)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x3b660]  g_str_hash+0x0
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/etp/Desktop/133backup/eclipse/core.29515)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

[Here](https://github.com/iamakashk/eclipse-crash-log/blob/main/eclipseError.log) is the link of the entire log file.

Here is my System Configuration:
Ubuntu 18.04.6
RAM 15.6 GiB
Processor Intel® Core™ i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz × 6
Graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
SSD 512 GB

My Eclipse configuration file :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms2048m
-Xmx8000m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: It seems to crash when calling the native [`libglib` library of GTK](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/). Which GTK version do you have and is this something that can be reproduced in the current Eclipse and GTK versions or only in your outdated Eclipse which is 4 releases behind?

Comment: I tried with latest version of eclipse as well. Facing the same issue. How do I confirm which libglib I am using ?

Comment: The question still says Eclipse 2021-03 which is 4 releases behind. See [here how to find out the GTK version you have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126141/6505250).